# upate caused"Secure boot violation - invalid signature detected"

Tags: 16.04, uefi

I have Ubuntu MATE 16.04 64 bit running on a refurbished ASUS (X550LA Notebook)F552L which had Windows 8 pre-installed when bought. I did an update to Windows 10. Then 12 months ago I had the drive formatted by an IT mate and Ubuntu MATE 16.04 installed.

2 days ago I used `synaptic` to update, then as I do occasionally used the `software updater` as an additional check, and I received a "Partial update - reboot?" (I'm sorry but I can't re-call the exact wording) Doing this caused `Secure boot violation - invalid signature detected`.

I found a short youtube that led me to disable "secure boot" and "launch CSM", which solved the problem. I understand a little about UEFI, and that it would be pre-installed on this machine but it's never appeared before.

Since getting the system up and running again, I've checked with the terminal using :-

```
 [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
```

which returned:-

```
UEFI
```

Also:-

```
dmesg | grep "EFI v"
```

which returned:-

```
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.31 by American Megatrends
```

I have some queries:-

1. Can I find out which update caused it and why?
2. Is it likely to "Come back" (a very hard one I know)
3. Is it likely the "problem" has gone way?
4. Am I at risk with secure boot disabled?

Prior to this I hadn't installed any new applications and I always use the Software centre for these if I do.

I have cold booted a number of times with no re-occurrence of the problem, but my knowledge of Ubuntu is scanty at best. I really would appreciate being directed to any previous answers, or any comments.
Hal.

Comment: The system offering a 'partial upgrade' is a bad sign. It usually occurs when you *already* had a serious package conflict the prevents a complete release-upgrade. Most often caused by packages from non-Ubuntu sources. The release-upgrade often exacerbates the problem, and **never** fixes the problem. Most users who tread this path either uninstall the non-Ubuntu packages to resolve the problem, or else do a clean reinstall.

Comment: Thank you for your comment user535733. I've carried out an update using synaptic and things are still working well. Hopefully I'll be able to avoid a reinstall.